# Can't start the Divine Fragmentation quest?

Tags: destiny-2

I've gone to the Vex Gate located in Sorrow's Harbor as indicated in the video below. According to the source, the quest Divine Fragmentation should drop when I defeat the boss after several waves of Vex.

I have done this several times, and each time the outcome is that the boss only drops a blue engram and nothing more.   Is it RNG related? Do I need specific DLC in order to access it? I'm confused why it's not dropping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some quest steps involve interacting with content which is only available if you own the Shadowkeep DLC. So you will need to buy Shadowkeep to obtain/complete the quest.

Comment: It they are able to go to the Moon then thy must own Shadowkeep. I have the Shadowkeep annual pass and the quest dropped first time for me so you may need to own both Shadowkeep and the Shadowkeep annual pass for it to drop.

Comment: @Colin You do actually get free roam access to every location, which includes the moon, you just can't do the actual mission content. [This reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/DestinyTheGame/wiki/d2faq/newlight#wiki_what_content_is_included_in_destiny_2.3A_new_light.3F) has a complete list of what is/isn't included.